# Jackson throwing errors

Tags: json, xml, hadoop, jackson, apache-storm

Trying to convert XML to JSON in STORM Trident My code worked fine in storm 0.9.1 version and now we upgraded to Latest Version of Storm 0.10.0 and we are getting the below errors if you have any idea on the cause please let me know?

```
11752 [Thread-56-b-1] ERROR b.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDefaultDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1522) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.findStdDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:167) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:132) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:403) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:352) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:461) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3804) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3698) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2714) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tda.trident.bolt.HdfsStateConvertor$HdfsFileOptions.execute(HdfsStateConvertor.java:278) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tda.trident.bolt.HdfsStateConvertor.updateState(HdfsStateConvertor.java:462) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tda.trident.bolt.HdfsUpdater.updateState(HdfsUpdater.java:15) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tda.trident.bolt.HdfsUpdater.updateState(HdfsUpdater.java:9) ~[StormTridentXmlNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at storm.trident.planner.processor.PartitionPersistProcessor.finishBatch(PartitionPersistProcessor.java:98) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at storm.trident.planner.SubtopologyBolt.finishBatch(SubtopologyBolt.java:152) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.finishBatch(TridentBoltExecutor.java:253) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.checkFinish(TridentBoltExecutor.java:286) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:360) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6214$tuple_action_fn__6216.invoke(executor.clj:670) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__6137.invoke(executor.clj:426) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5713.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6214$fn__6227$fn__6278.invoke(executor.clj:808) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
```

My maven shade output while building POM is as shown below.

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:1.4:shade (default) @ StormTridentXmlNew ---
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.storm:storm-hdfs:jar:0.10.0.2.3.2.0-2950 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.hmsonline:storm-jms:jar:0.2.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.tibco.ems:tibjms:jar:5.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.6.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.7.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.7.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including asm:asm:jar:3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml. I would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of storm is having jackson-core-2.3.1.jar in its lib folder and my fat jar that i create using maven is having another version of jackson dependencies. That is why when i submit my jar in storm cluster it is throwing these No such method errors at run-time..

**I changed My POM to use the same version of jackson dependencies what storm is using and everything is working fine.**

Comment: Meaning, you actually did not want Jackson 2.6?

Comment: I need xml to json marshalling. jackson has this feature in the version which STORM is internally using that will suffice for me.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have many versions of jackson jars and your class path refers some Jackson jar prior to 2.6 at runtime.

Class ResolvedType introduced isReferenceType() from version 2.6 onwards. Please refer link below:

http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/ResolvedType.html&ei=ochB8Ipc&lc=en-IN&geid=10&s=1&m=71&ts=1454581842&sig=ALL1Aj7I2EAu3AoKmOu6FKbtFTTuKU02Bg#a-isReferenceType()

Please ensure you refer the right version or a higher one at runtime. You may remove/delete the older Jackson jars if not required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue seems to come from multiple versions of jackson classes in the classpath. You may remove the unwanted versions off. As of this writing. The current version for jackson isis 2.7.1.